# scikit learn use multinomial naive bayes for a trigram classifier?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I have taken a look and try out the scikit-learn's tutorial on its Multinomial naive bayes classifier.

I want to use it to classify text documents, and the catch about the NB is that it treats its P(document|label) as a product of all its independent features (words). Right now, I need to try out doing 3 trigram classifier whereby the P(document|label) = P(wordX|wordX-1,wordX-2,label) * P(wordX-1|wordX-2,wordX-3, label).

Where scikit learn supports anything I can implement this language model and extend the NB classifier to perform classification based on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`CountVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer) will extract trigrams for you (using `ngram_range=(3, 3)`). The [text feature extraction documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#limitations-of-the-bag-of-words-representation) introduces this. Then, just use [`MultinomialNB`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html) exactly like before with the transformed feature matrix.

Note that this is actually modeling:

P(document | label) = P(word<sub>X</sub>, word<sub>X-1</sub>, word<sub>X-2</sub> | label) * P(word<sub>X-1</sub>, word<sub>X-2</sub>, word<sub>X-3</sub> | label) * ...

How different is that? Well, that first term can be written as

P(word<sub>X</sub>, word<sub>X-1</sub>, word<sub>X-2</sub> | label) = P(word<sub>X</sub> | word<sub>X-1</sub>, word<sub>X-2</sub>, label) * P(word<sub>X-1</sub>, word<sub>X-2</sub> | label)

Of course, all the other terms can be written that way too, so you end up with (dropping the subscripts and the conditioning on the label for brevity):

P(X | X-1, X-2) P(X-1 | X-2, X-3) ... P(3 | 2, 1) P(X-1, X-2) P(X-2, X-3) ... P(2, 1)

Now, P(X-1, X-2) can be written as P(X-1 | X-2) P(X-2). So if we do that for all those terms, we have

P(X | X-1, X-2) P(X-1 | X-2, X-3) ... P(3 | 2, 1) P(X-1 | X-2) P(X-2 | X-3) ... P(2 | 1) P(X-2) P(X-1) ... P(1)

So this is actually like using trigrams, bigrams, and unigrams (though not estimating the bigram/unigram terms directly).

Comment: Impeccable answer, just that it's ngram_range. Also, question here. assuming each tuple (word1, word2, word3) is one feature, how does the MultinomialNB  knows of this conditional probability dependency?

Comment: Whoops, sorry about the typo. And: it doesn't actually know about the conditional dependencies. One trigram feature means that it's modeling the first equation listed. It's just a fact of probabilities that that amounts to modeling trigrams, bigrams, unigrams independently, except that it drops P(X | X-1) P(X) P(X-1) and that the estimates are based on trigrams and so are probably worse than if you directly estimated the formula at the end.

Comment: Dougal, its really a great explanation. But what do you mean by  "estimates are based on trigrams and so are probably worse than if you directly estimated the formula at the end."

Comment: It's true that `P(X, X-1, X-2) = P(X | X-1, X-2) P(X-2 | X-1) P(X-1)`. But when you model the joint distribution of trigrams as above, you're estimating `P(X, X-1, X-2)` by counting the number of times that you see that trigram. If you wanted to directly estimate `P(X|X-1, X-2) P(X-1|X-2) P(X-2)`, it'd instead be based on the counts of the trigram, the bigram, and the unigram. Your estimates for the bigram and especially unigram probabilities will be better (lower variance), because there are fewer possibilities to see. So the estimate is likely to be worse than if you used all three.

Comment: oh wow, i didn't realize this, but now that u say so, it does makes sense. thank you, your explanation made my day!